# How to install TFLearn on Anaconda/PyCharm Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda, tflearn

pip install tflearn is leading hdf5 error, and I cant find a way to install tflearn on Anaconda/Pycharm. Please help?

Comment: did you try pip3 install tflearn? and please show the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple approach for Anaconda.

Go [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn) (https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn) to make a clone of the tflean repository or download a copy in a zip form. Extract the files in the zip file.

Launch the anaconda prompt and navigate to the folder that contains the extracted downloaded files.

Then run:

```
python setup.py install
```

You can find my source from [here](http://tflearn.org/installation/) (http://tflearn.org/installation/)

I hope this helps.